# How does Spring Boot app exit after it runs a Cloud Task?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, shutdown, spring-cloud-task

Related to this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-task
and this example:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/timestamp

How does the Spring Boot app exit after it runs the task? Where is the code/configuration to tell the Spring Boot application that once the task is finished it should shut down gracefully?
I'm looking at the Timestamp example:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/timestamp/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/timestamp/TaskApplication.java
which runs the task, prints the timestamp, and then shuts down, but I'm not understanding *how* the application (Spring Boot) shuts down after the task completes?

Answer (score 0):

A JVM will automatically shut down when there are no daemon threads running. So with Spring Cloud Task (and any Java application), once your processing is complete, unless you have another non-daemon thread running, the JVM will automatically terminate.